# LINQ: Como puedo obtener los valores minimos y fecha de cada grupo

Tags: linq

Tengo dos tablas MySQL que están relacionadas. Mi propósito es obtener los valores mínimos de cada grupo y las fechas asociadas a cada valor mínimo encontrado.

```
                             TABLA 1
> -------------+----------------+----------------+--------------+
> -- Codigo -- | -- IdGrupo1 -- | -- IdGrupo2 -- | -- Estado -- |
> -------------+----------------+----------------+--------------+
>    ZZ-100    |    11111111    |     1110000    |      1       |
> -------------+----------------+----------------+--------------+
>    ZZ-200    |    55555555    |     5550000    |      1       |
> -------------+----------------+----------------+--------------+
>    ZZ-300    |    99999999    |     9990000    |      1       |
```

La Tabla 2 es la encargada de registrar los nuevos valores.

```
                                TABLA 2
> ---------+-----------------------+----------------+----------------+
> - Value -| ------- Date -------- | -- IdGrupo1 -- | -- IdGrupo2 -- |
> ---------+-----------------------+----------------+----------------+
>    10    |  2020-08-21 01:10:06  |    99999999    |     9990000    |
> ---------+-----------------------+----------------+----------------+
>    15    |  2020-08-21 01:20:06  |    99999999    |     9990000    |
> ---------+-----------------------+----------------+----------------+
>    20    |  2020-08-21 01:30:06  |    99999999    |     9990000    |
> ---------+-----------------------+----------------+----------------+
>    115   |  2020-08-21 01:40:06  |    55555555    |     5550000    |
> ---------+-----------------------+----------------+----------------+
>    120   |  2020-08-21 01:40:06  |    55555555    |     5550000    |
> ---------+-----------------------+----------------+----------------+
>    90    |  2020-08-21 01:50:06  |    11111111    |     1110000    |
> ---------+-----------------------+----------------+----------------+
>    100   |  2020-08-21 01:50:06  |    11111111    |     1110000    |
```

He realizado muchas pruebas y aun lo logro conseguir la respuesta correcta, la mejor aproximación la obtuve con la siguiente consulta:

```
var query = Tabla2                                              //Outer Table
            .Join(Tabla1,                                       //Inner Table to join
                         p => new { p.IdGrupo1, p.IdGrupo2 },   //Condition from outer table
                         e => new { e.IdGrupo1, e.IdGrupo2 },   //Condition from inner table
                         (p, e) => new {                        //Result
                                          Codigo = e.Codigo,                                          
                                          Value = p.Value,
                                          Fecha = p.Date })         
            .GroupBy(gb => new { gb.Codigo })           
            .OrderBy(ob => ob.Key.Codigo)
            .Select(s => new {  Codigo = s.Key.Codigo, 
                                Value = (double?)s.Min(a => a.Value),
                                Fecha = "?" })  // TODO: Falta implementar la fecha.
            .ToList();
```

El resultado de mi consulta:

```
> -------------+-------------+-------------+
> -- Codigo -- | -- Value -- | -- Fecha -- | 
> -------------+-------------+-------------+
>    ZZ-100    |      90     |      ?      | 
> -------------+-------------+-------------+
>    ZZ-200    |     115     |      ?      |
> -------------+-------------+-------------+
>    ZZ-300    |      10     |      ?      |
```

Solo me falta agregar las fechas para cada valor mínimo encontrado.
Que debo hacer para poder integrarlo en mi consulta? Por mas que intento, no lo he logrado :(